# csv wont download with url

Tags: c#, csv, url, download

I want to automatically download a `csv` in c# with a url. When I run the code I get the error message

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Dispite this, I can download the `csv` by going to the website and manually clicking through and downloading it (doesn't need a login etc), but if I copy the download url to the address bar, it gives me a blank page, without the download.

Is there a way to allow the csv to be downloaded with a url?

Comment: It would be helpfull, if you could provide the link, if it's nothing secret. Besides that, have you tried using another browser or the incognito mode?

 btw: providing the sourcecode could make it easier to find errors

Comment: Url I'm trying to use is: https://calendar.fxstreet.com/eventdate/?f=csv&v=2&timezone=UTC&rows=&view=range&start=20170917&end=20170930&countrycode=AR%2CAU%2CAT%2CBE%2CBR%2CCA%2CCL%2CCN%2CCO%2CCZ%2CDK%2CEMU%2CFI%2CFR%2CDE%2CGR%2CHK%2CHU%2CIS%2CIN%2CID%2CIE%2CIT%2CJP%2CMX%2CNL%2CNZ%2CNO%2CPL%2CPT%2CRO%2CRU%2CSG%2CSK%2CZA%2CKR%2CES%2CSE%2CCH%2CTR%2CUK%2CUS&volatility=0&culture=en&columns=CountryCurrency%2CCountdown

Comment: Also the manual download works in incognito

Comment: Using Firefox, Chrome or Edge I do get an 401 as well. As @realbart mentioned there might be some kind of authentication that you are not aware of. Have you tried load the Data through the [API](http://api.fxstreet.com/Calendar/V2)? because your link looks different from the examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably authenticate when connecting to the server.

Your browser has several ways of authenticating without you seeing. Your browser may be using Windows Authentication or it has cached your credentials. You can check this by trying the download from an anonymous (incognito) session. Also, if you use the f12 developer tools in your browser, you sometimes see two calls to the same url, one receiving a 401, the second a 500 status code. This is also an indication the browser authenticates for you.

*Finally, the server software developers may have chosen to return a 401 status code for any other reason. If that is the case, you should contact them. If that's not possible, you can try to mimic the call your browser makes by sending the same request headers.*

(I do not thing the file type csv matters.)